# How to format a currency with trailing ISO code in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, format

Given a value of `1000.5`, I want to format it as `1,000.50 USD` (where the **trailing** currency code is the most relevant part). Performance is also important, as the formatting will be issued for millions of values. Hence, regex is discouraged.

Can you accomplish this using [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) or some other standardized JavaScript number formatting API?

**Example:**

```
const formatter = Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD', currencyDisplay: 'code' })
formatter.format(1000.5)
```

**Actual:**

> USD 1,000.50

**Expected:**

> 1,000.50 USD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple function that formats with a trailing ISO code.

```
   function FormatWithTrailingISO(currency, type,num) {
    const formatter = Intl.NumberFormat(type, {
      style: "currency",
      currency: currency,
      currencyDisplay: "code",
    });
    return formatter.format(num).replace(currency, "") + " " + currency;
   }
```

Usage:

```
console.log(FormatWithTrailingISO("USD", "en-US", 1000.5).trim());
```